# Material-UI-next Theme not being applied to circular progress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have updated my theme according to the docs but the circular progress continues to use the default primary color, not the one specified in the theme. Ultimately I'd like to be able to make the theme adjustable via the end user, using mobx computed values to adjust the theme, but currently I can't even get it to work with a static theme.

```
import {MuiThemeProvider} from "material-ui/styles"
import Loading from "../common/components/Loading";
import {createMuiTheme} from "material-ui";


const testingTheme = createMuiTheme({
    primary: {
        main: '#67e2ff',
        light: '#a0ffff',
        dark: '#1eb0cc',
        contrastText: '#3b3f42'
    },

    secondary: {
        main: '#590ce8',
        light: '#9549ff',
        dark: '#0000b4',
        contrastText: '#fefefe'
    }});

/**
 * The AppContainer handles all of the logical functionality that has to happen at the root level.
 * A prime example is the MuiThemeProvider, that must be the parent of all other rendered components.
 * To change the muiTheme we use the AppContainer to render the MuiThemeProvider
 */
@inject("uiStore") @observer
export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.uiStore);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={testingTheme}>
                {this.props.uiStore.initialized ? <App/> : <Loading size={10}/>}
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My definition for the theme was wrong, I was missing the root palette property.

```
const testingTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#67e2ff',
            light: '#a0ffff',
            dark: '#1eb0cc',
            contrastText: '#3b3f42'
        },

        secondary: {
            main: '#590ce8',
            light: '#9549ff',
            dark: '#0000b4',
            contrastText: '#fefefe'
        }
    }
});
```